# ul with links remains selected

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a side bar menu composed of ul->li->a, styled with css to look as a vertical menu on the left side.

I just noticed that when I choose an option a thin grew dotted line surrounds the box(button of the menu) that I selected. To me this looks "wrong", is there a way to prevent this from being visible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a:active {
  outline: none;
}